# Only allow certain user accounts onto a page

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for a method to find an account, check if it holds a certain variable & then allow it access to a page (basically like an admin-only page).
This project is like a School CMS System, and so I want to make it so only teachers can actually access the page so they can add more students, etc.

Here's what I have tried already:

```
if( $_SESSION['teacher']=='1'){
(then show any other users another page:)
    header("Location: demo.com/home.php");
   }
```

(imagine demo.com is a real domain)

This snippet actually lets every user onto the page and not just teachers - so it does not work for me.

From this snippet, I am trying to let only people that have '1' on their teacher section in the database get onto the page.
I am using 1 for teachers and 0 for students.

Database Image:

[image: Database Image]

Basically I only want users that are teachers to view this page.

I am happy to expand more on the topic & share more images on the database structure & login system - but my main question is 'How do I restrict access to a page?'

Code to start a session:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="") {
    header("Location: home.php");
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
    
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    
    $email = $DBcon->real_escape_string($email);
    $password = $DBcon->real_escape_string($password);
    
    $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT user_id, email, password FROM tbl_users WHERE email='$email'");
    $row=$query->fetch_array();
    
    $count = $query->num_rows; // if email/password are correct returns must be 1 row
    
    if (password_verify($password, $row['password']) && $count==1) {
        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['user_id'];
        header("Location: home.php");
    } else {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Invalid Username or Password !
                </div>";
    }
    $DBcon->close();
}
?>
```

Check if session is open/exists code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['userSession'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['userSession']);
$userRow=$query->fetch_array();
$DBcon->close();

?>
```

Comment: i have edited my answer try it and update your question if you need more

Comment: I see where you add user_id to the session, but where did you add 'teacher' flag? Maybe you should add right after user_id. So in your select add teacher to selected columns, and after simply save it to session.

Answer (score 0):

First, you make sure what value is stored in $_SESSION['teacher'].
Simply echo the value

> echo $_SESSION['teacher'];

Get the value from 'teacher' column

> $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT user_id, email, password, teacher FROM tbl_users
> WHERE email='$email'");

Then create a session

> $_SESSION['teacher'] = $row['teacher'];

**Complete code**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="") {
    header("Location: home.php");
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
    
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    
    $email = $DBcon->real_escape_string($email);
    $password = $DBcon->real_escape_string($password);
    
    $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT user_id, email, password, teacher FROM tbl_users WHERE email='$email'");
    $row=$query->fetch_array();
    
    $count = $query->num_rows; // if email/password are correct returns must be 1 row
    
    if (password_verify($password, $row['password']) && $count==1) {
        $_SESSION['userSession'] = array('user_id'=>$row['user_id'],'teacher'=>$row['teacher']);
        header("Location: home.php");
    } else {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Invalid Username or Password !
                </div>";
    }
    $DBcon->close();
}
?>
```

**Check if session is open/exists code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['userSession'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['userSession']['user_id']);
$userRow=$query->fetch_array();
$DBcon->close();

?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216689/discussion-on-answer-by-user3772091-only-allow-certain-user-accounts-onto-a-page).